# Using $pull in Mongodb to remove a deeply embedded object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to delete (`$pull`) an object from an array that's embedded. (Using javascript/node.js driver.)

Here is the sample data, where one, two, three are the levels:

```
{
    one : "All",
    one : [
        {
        name: "People",
        two: [
            { 
            three_id: 123,
            three: "Jonny",
            },
            { 
            three_id: 456,
            three: "Bobby",
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        name: "Animals",
        two: [
            { 
            three_id: 828,
            three: "Cat",
            },
            { 
            three_id: 282,
            three: "Dog",
            }
        ]
        }
    ]   
}
```

In this example, I'm trying get rid of "Bobby".

I can successfully match the document at the "three level" if I want, like this:

```
db.test.find({"one.two.three_id" : 456});
```

However, I've no idea how to eliminate that record using `update`. Here are some attempts, none of which work:

```
// failed attempts
db.test.update({"one.two.three_id" : 456}, {$pull:{'one.$.two.$.three_id': 456}});
db.test.update({"one.two.three_id" : 456}, {$pull:{'three_id': 456}});

// deletes entire level two "People"
db.test.update({"one.two.three_id" : 456}, {$pull: {one: {two : {$elemMatch: {'three_id': 456}}}}});
```

I read that you cannot use two positional `$ operators` and that you have to know the index position for the second one. However, I want to avoid having to use the index of the embedded dictionary I want to delete.

reference:
Mongodb on pull

> http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of the key in your `$pull` object needs to be the path of the array that you're targeting.  This appears to work:

```
db.test.update(
    {'one.two.three_id': 456},
    {$pull: {'one.$.two': {three_id: 456}}}
);
```

It looks like the `$` represents the index of the *first* matched array level in this case so it works even though we're matching across multiple nesting levels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried it but I'm getting for the 100th time `$err : Unsupported projection option: one.$.two, code : 13097` I'm testing using mongo shell.

Comment: Ignore my above comment. Your solution does work. I tried it again and I had a missing period. GREAT.

Comment: Learning note: I tried to also use a simply query to shorten the expression, and got message: "Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array." So, the query sets up the use of $ operator.

Comment: @cathy.sasaki Right, but you could also use a query object of `{'one.name': 'People'}`.  It just depends on how you want to find the `one` element to target.

Comment: Got it. I see how it works. As long as you step into the array in anyway so that $ has a reference.