# how to remove an object inside the array of objects in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to remove an object inside the array of objects and I am doing this

```
router.post("/delVendAttach", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let vend = await Vendors.findOneAndUpdate({ "level1.email": req.body.email }, {
      $pull: {
        "level2.attachments": {
          _id: req.body.id
        }
      }
    })
    return res.status(200).send("Attachment Deleted Successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    return res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});
```

[Here is the img of db collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x9q0.png)

Comment: your code correct !, can you share what the problem ?..

Answer (score 0):

I think you find from `level1.email` and remove from `level2` that the problem.
Try below code may be works for you !

```
let vend = await Vendors.findOneAndUpdate({ "level1.email": req.body.email }, {
  $pull: {
    "level1.attachments": {
      _id: req.body.id
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Nope attachments exist in level2

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Using $pull in Mongodb to remove a deeply embedded object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435123/using-pull-in-mongodb-to-remove-a-deeply-embedded-object)

Comment: Not working showing same response

Comment: So if you are replace `ONE_OF_YOUR_COLLECTIONS` with like `Users` and then filter one by `Id`. You get a `User`. My user looks like `Id(string), Tracks(Array of strings)` So then inside the `$push` mongo method `Tracks` is the array we want to update inside the user with the `req.body.Tracks` which is an array of strings.

Comment: So think we have an object in the DB that looks like `{ Id:1, Elements:[1,2,3] }` we are filtering to this object by their Id what is 1 in our case then with `$push` we tell to Mongo DB that replace our array with the input one. And with `upsert` set to true we not replacing it we are including the `input array` to the array that is already in the DB. If our input array is `[1,2,3,4,5]` then the DB will updates our object's Tracks array to `[1,2,3,4,5]` if we would like to delete from this simple just send `[1,2,3,4]` then the DB will have `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Look up https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/ for more information

Comment: it is ok for $push but not for $pull

Comment: This question was already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435123/using-pull-in-mongodb-to-remove-a-deeply-embedded-object

Comment: It's should work fine based on the other question's answer but let me know you were successful full or not.